# Mobius Transformation, Conway text

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Assume that $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ lie on a line or circle C.

By what I just mention above, there exist a mobius tran $T$ that takes the real numbers $x_2, x_3, x_4$ to $z_2, z_3,z_4$ respectively. Since there is only one such line or circle and since we know that Mobius take $\mathbb{R}_{\infty}$ to a line or circle, we see that there exist a real number $x_1$ such that $T(x_1) = z_1$.

Since the cross ratio is preserved under a Mobius trans, then $ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(T(x_1),T(x_2),T(x_3),T(x_4))=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$

But since $x_i$ is all real numbers, its cross ratio is also real, which show that the cross ratio of $z_i$ is also real.

Comment: Do you already know that the cross-ratio is preserved under Möbius transformations?

Comment: @David yes, i also learn that there exist a unique mobius trans betweeen three distinct points on the plane. but i didn't learn that mobius take circles to circles yet.

Comment: Khoa ta, you should leave the original question, and add the new information after the word **Edit**. What's left doesn't make sense on its own.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. I was suggesting $1, 0, \infty$ and you've taken $x_2, x_3, x_4$. Note that $x_1$ could also be $\infty$.

Comment: @David thank you for reply, I'm new to this site, if $x_1 $ is $\infty$, then does it still hold true that the cross ratio of $x_i$ is real??

Comment: Yes.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ and $z_4$ lie on a line or circle $C$. Let $\phi$ be the Möbius transformation taking $1, 0, \infty$ to $z_2$, $z_3$, $z_4$, respectively. The image of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ under $\phi$ is a line or circle passing through $z_2$, $z_3$ and $z_4$. Since there is only one such line or circle, it must be $C$. Therefore $\phi^{-1}(z_1) \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. But $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = \phi^{-1}(z_1)$.

Comment: thank you very much, i got it now, i'm reading the text by myself so the only help I can get is thru this site, thank u again

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but regard what I ask you, I have another way of showing that, can you check to see if my reasoning is correct??,

Comment: Write your argument as an edit to the question.

Comment: sorry for taking so long, I accidentally edit your comment instead of mine, thank you again,